# Playframework Secure module and Internationalization

Tags: security, internationalization, playframework

I'm using the standard Secure module from Play! 1.2.2.

In [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/v3hOi9ylhGs/discussion) I've seen how to copy the view template for the Secure module:

```
play secure:ov --css
play secure:ov --login
play secure:ov --layout
```

or one can just copy yourself the relevant files to `app/views/Secure` and `/public/stylesheets`.

But my authentication should be in a different **language** than English. The error messages are in the module source, in the Play! distribution: `models/secure/conf/messages`.

Is there any proper way of customising that file without touching the module source itself? Creating a `conf/secure/messages` in my application does not have any effect.

The message catalogue is not only used by the view - which I could easily change - but also by the Secure controller, when generating an error message. I'd like to avoid forking the Secure module just for these six messages.

Thanks for reading, Viktor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Secure module is usually "forked" and customized for many applications, don't be afraid to do so. In theory removing the keys from the models/secure/conf/messages and moving them to the app conf/messages should do it.

But if you have problems, just copy the contents of the module to your project. You are already customizing most of it (the look and feel) so copying 1 class, 1 annotation and 1 tag should be a bug deal :)

Comment: Modifying the look and feel is one thing, but I'd prefer not to touch the Controller. If there ever is a security fix, I'd like to have people just update their Play installation without having to patch anything afterwards. - So I didn't miss any easy way where one could avoid touching anything in the Play! distribution? :-)

Comment: @cato_minor to be honest the default security controller is quite basic, so in many applications you need to extend it. Let's say you want to support OpenID login, or BCrypt, or... It's more a demo on how to apply security than a truly useful one. If you still want to keep it as a module, try with removing the keys from the messages file in the module and add them to the app file.